# Created a session multisport

Tags: garmin, connectiq

With ConnectIQ, I would like to make a multisport session but in the documentation I can just make span.
I can save multiple activity but it is in so many files in Garmin connect is separated while I wish it was considered a multisport activity.

In the documention of file creation made, it is indicated that it is possible.

http://www.thisisant.com/developer/resources/tech-support/